# How to set Orientation Preference in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

On my flutter app, I need the screen to be portrait mode only. Either portraitUp or portraitDown. So I added this code in the main file:

```
void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
    DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
    DeviceOrientation.portraitDown,
  ]);
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

But when I tested this on an emulator. It only stays in `portraitUp`. Even when I switch the emulator to `portraitDown`. What's causing this and how do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

`SystemChrome` code should be inside the `build` method of the main widget which returns `MaterialApp`.

Or do it natively,

In your `AndroidManifest.xml`, in `<activity>` tag add this `android:screenOrientation="portrait"`. Like,

```
<activity
...
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
>
...
</activity>
```

And in iOS, `select target (Runner) > General > Deployment Info > Device Orientation` and select desired orientations

Comment: I've tried that. I've also tried using running `runApp()` using `.then()` but the result is still the same.

Comment: Then set it on AndroidManifest.xml, in activity tag add this android:screenOrientation="portrait". And in iOS, select target > General > Deployment Info > Device Orientation and select desired orientations